# Newton's Principia Naturalis: question on Corollary III?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, history

I'm reading [Newton's Principia Naturalis](https://archive.org/details/newtonspmathema00newtrich/page/n91/mode/2up) and have a question on Corollary III p86:

> The quantity of motion, which is collected by taking the sum of the motions directed towards the same parts, and difference of those that are directed to contrary parts, suffers no change from the action of the bodies among themselves.

Does anyone know what this represents in mathematical terms?  Is it as follows?

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n |\vec p_i| = c = P
$$

$$
\frac {dP} {dt} = P =0
$$

where $c$ is a constant representing the momentum of a close system and $\vec p_i$ is a momemtum vector for body $I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems reasonable, although the modulus should be omitted, like this

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \vec p_i = c$$

Imagine just two particles attracting each other along a line, due to gravity, and all motion being along that line.

If the modulus is included, both speeds and momenta could increase as they fell towards each other, but without the modulus the sum of the momenta stays constant.

It's valid in any specific direction, so the $p_i$ needs to represent the component of momentum of part $i$ of the body in the specified direction.  The expressions 'same parts' and 'contrary parts' seem to mean positive and negative.